# SQL Get Users By One Group And Incremental Position

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - a `users` table and a `group` table.

Users are uniquely identified by `user_id` in the `users` table, but can have multiple entries in the `group` table.

The group table dictates which `group` each user is in by the `name` and `user_id` columns.

The entries in the `group` table have a `position` column which is an integer that is manually incremented for each user's entry.

I'm trying to write a query that returns all users in group name `A`, that don't have group `B` as the next incremental number that was in the `position` column of the group `A` entry.

In other words, all entries that are in group `A` at any `position`, must have a subsequent entry in group `B` as the next increment of `position`. I want to find all entries where that is NOT true.

```
GROUPS TABLE

| user_id       | name          | position  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| ---------:|
| 1             | A             | 14        |
| 1             | B             | 15        |
| 2             | A             | 22        |
| 2             | B             | 24        |
| 2             | C             | 23        | <-- Query Should return this row
```

So far, I'm able to get users that are in group `A` and not `B`, but I don't know how to do the position part, as I believe it must have to use some sort of variable or something.

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM groups g
WHERE 
  exists (
    SELECT 1 from groups WHERE user_id = g.user_id AND name = 'A'
  )
  and not exists (
    SELECT 1 from groups WHERE user_id = g.user_id AND name != 'B'
  )
```

Comment: could u please post sample data

Comment: I added the sample data and table visuals.

Comment: where is users table

Comment: Users table is arbitrary, It's just to explain the context.

Comment: basically a self join based on position will give u data about next row in the same row. then you can simply filter out relevant data. (more or less as suggested by Gordon)

Comment: Why do you want this row:`2 | C | 23` since there is this row: `2 | B | 24` with `24` being the next increment of `23`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to write a query that returns all users in group name A,
>   that don't have group B as the next incremental number that was in the
>   position column of the group A entry

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM groups g
WHERE
  name = 'A'
  AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from groups 
    WHERE 
      user_id = g.user_id 
      AND 
      name = 'B' 
      AND 
      position = (select min(position) from groups where position > g.position)
  )
```

Comment: The position value is not auto-incremented based on the row entry. It's incremented manually based on each user's entry. It counts each user's group entry.

Comment: What about `SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM groups g
WHERE
  name = 'B' 
  AND 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from groups 
    WHERE 
      user_id = g.user_id 
      AND 
      name = 'A' 
      AND 
      position = g.position - 1
  )`

Comment: It only works if `position` is auto-incremented for each entry. Each entry could have any position based on how many entries a user has. Can you update your answer. I think it's almost right.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `left join`:

```
select g.*
from groups g left join
     groups gb
     on gb.user_id = g.user_id and
        gb.position = g.position + 1 and
        gb.name = 'B'
where g.name = 'A' and gb.name is null;
```

Comment: What is the `is null` part for?

Comment: @Dangerman1988 . . . "I want to find all entries where that is NOT true."  It returns the A rows where the next row is not B.